# How to use QGIS Raster Calculator for computing slope?

Tags: qgis, slope

I am using QGIS 3.10 in my Windows 10. I want to create a slope of a DEM layer. First I used "Slope" in the Raster Terrain Analysis. Then I used Raster calculator to find the slope less than 10. The resulting layer only has values 0 to 1. What is wrong with this? I am expecting the values should be 0 - 9 right?

[DEM DATA](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ruI6vCVA8EzMDcfxQfRtwwRb83MnnUk1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: if you use "yourraster@1"<=10, the raster calculator asigns a pixel value of 1 to any pixel whose value is equal or less than 10. All pixels greater than 10 will be 0. If you want to have the original pixel values you have to do as follows ("yourraster@1"<=10)*"yourraster@1". Check this: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/es/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand